# performFetch creating diffable data source snapshots with too much data

Tags: core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

After executing an [`NSBatchBatchInsertRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest) and calling [`fetchedResultsController.performFetch()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscon%E2%80%A6), the frc’s delegate method [`controller(_:didChangeContentWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/3235742-controller) is called with a `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, NSManagedObjectID>` that unexpectedly contains *all* data in Core Data.

However I've only just inserted *new* data into Core Data. Applying a snapshot with all the data at each `performFetch` is causing a high memory load and jittery scrolling when I test this with thousands of cells.

Is there a way to make this delegate method only receive a snapshot with incremental updates to the data source?

## Code

Here's how the `NSFetchedResultsController` is created:

```
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<MyManagedObject>(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: persistentContainer.viewContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil
    )
```

The `NSFetchRequest`:

```
let fetchRequest = MyManagedObject.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "value", ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10
```

The snapshot is applied in this `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method below.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
    dataSource.apply(snapshot as NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, NSManagedObjectID>, animatingDifferences: false)
}
```

The most obvious solution to me was implementing this delegate method only, but that method doesn't seem to get called:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith diff: CollectionDifference<NSManagedObjectID>) {
    print(diff)
}
```

## Data source to Core Data connection

- When the data source is asked to make a cell for a specific `NSManagedObjectID`, the right `MyManagedObject` is found for that `NSManagedObjectID` using `fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.object(with:)`.
- Then the `MyManagedObject` is converted into an `Item`, which is finally used to configure the cell.

Comment: why are you using a diffable datasource with NSFetchedResultsController? the diffable datasource needs to figure out what the changes were, but the NSFetchedResultsController already knows what they are and tells you in the delegate.

Comment: Hi Jon, you’ve brought up the exact mystery I’m hoping to solve: why the FRC tells the delegate *all* the data has changed, when only new data has been stored in CD (via batch insert).

Comment: As for why I’m using a diffable data source with the FRC: the connection is natural seeing that there is an FRC delegate method built for this purpose `func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference)`

Comment: I am not clear when you care calling the performFetch(). it should just be called once for the lifecycle of the FRC, and there is no reason to call it after you performed an insert.

Comment: `performFetch` is called after the successful completion of every batch insert. That’s to get the UI to refresh with the newly stored data. Is there a better way?

Comment: that is very strange. generally you do performFetch once, and then the FRC monitors the changes to coredata and can make a diff. If you are doing a performFetch it reboots the FRC and doesn't do a diff.  I think you should close this question and ask a new one on why your FRC is not updating. There are a few reasons why a FRC does not get the changes from core data. what does your core data stack look like?